# How to clone or copy a set in Python?

Tags: python, set, clone, shallow-copy

For copying a list: `shallow_copy_of_list = old_list[:]`.

For copying a dict: `shallow_copy_of_dict = dict(old_dict)`.

But for a `set`, I was worried that a similar thing wouldn't work, because saying `new_set = set(old_set)` would give a set of a set?

But it does work. So I'm posting the question and answer here for reference. In case anyone else has the same confusion.

Answer (score 86):

Both of these will give a duplicate of a set:

```
shallow_copy_of_set = set(old_set)
```

Or:

```
shallow_copy_of_set = old_set.copy() #Which is more readable.
```

The reason that the first way above **doesn't** give a set of a set, is that the proper syntax for that would be `set([old_set])`. Which wouldn't work, because `set`s can't be elements in other `set`s, because they are unhashable by virtue of being mutable. However, this isn't true for `frozenset`s, so e.g. `frozenset(frozenset(frozenset([1,2,3]))) == frozenset([1, 2, 3])`.

So a rule of thumb for replicating any of instance of the basic data structures in Python (lists, dict, set, frozenset, string):

```
a2 = list(a)      #a is a list
b2 = set(b)       #b is a set
c2 = dict(c)      #c is a dict
d2 = frozenset(d) #d is a frozenset
e2 = str(e)       #e is a string
#All of the above give a (shallow) copy.
```

So, if `x` is either of those types, then

```
shallow_copy_of_x = type(x)(x) #Highly unreadable! But economical.
```

Note that only `dict`, `set` and `frozenset` have the built-in `copy()` method. It would probably be a good idea that lists and strings had a `copy()` method too, for uniformity and readability. But they don't, at least in Python 2.7.3 which I'm testing with.

Comment: Note: In 3.3+, `list`s have a `.copy()` method. `str` does not, but it also doesn't need one; it's immutable, so copying is meaningless (for general sequence types, you can slice with `[:]`, which works on `str`, it's just pointless). If you really need to handle shallow-copying arbitrary types (silently reusing the existing object for immutable types like `str`), you'd just use the `copy` module, and do `shallow_copy_of_x = copy.copy(x)` (which is significantly clearer than `type(x)(x)`, and handles types where the constructor doesn't accept an instance of the class).

Answer (score 12):

Besides the `type(x)(x)` hack, you can import `copy` module to make either shallow copy or deep copy:

```
In [29]: d={1: [2,3]}

In [30]: sd=copy.copy(d)
    ...: sd[1][0]=321
    ...: print d
{1: [321, 3]}

In [31]: dd=copy.deepcopy(d)
    ...: dd[1][0]=987
    ...: print dd, d
{1: [987, 3]} {1: [321, 3]}
```

From the docstring:

```
Definition: copy.copy(x)
Docstring:
Shallow copy operation on arbitrary Python objects.
```