# I m suffering from a very strange type issue with list of sets

Tags: python, list, set

i made a list

```
edges = [{1,6},{3,4}]
vertices = set([1,2,3,4,5,6])
exclude = set([2,5])
result = list()

for edge in edges:     
    for item in vertices - edge - exclude:
        #conactenate items with edge and store in result
        val = edge
        val.add(item)
        if not val in result:
            result.append(val)
```

I wanted a result like

```
result = [{1,3,6},{1,4,6},{1,3,4},{3,4,6}]
```

but got instead

```
[{1, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 6}]
```

and meanwhile i checked my 'edges' list i found it as:

```
[{1, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 3, 4, 6}]
```

Help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone or copy a set in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200969/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-set-in-python). As currently written, you're modifying `edge` during each iteration of the inner loop. The variables `val` and `edge` refer to the same object.

Comment: To summarise the above, the fix you want is `val = edge.copy()` in place of `val = edge`. But read the detail to see why.

Comment: Also, for future posts, try to use more informative titles. Titles like "strange set issue" are not informative and are unlikely to be searched.

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing that out, i generally code in C and recently switched to python... So sometimes just get stuck with minor mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Try `copy` the `edge`:

```
edges = [{1,6},{3,4}]
vertices = set([1,2,3,4,5,6])
exclude = set([2,5])
result = list()

for edge in edges:     
    for item in vertices - edge - exclude:
        #conactenate items with edge and store in result
        val = edge.copy()
        val.add(item)
        if not val in result:
            result.append(val)
```

Comment: Sets have a `copy` method, you don't need `copy.copy`.

Comment: It's generally best not to answer duplicate questions.

Comment: @alaniwi Thank you for pointing out that. I edited it.

Comment: Thank you.. geek